# Can I add multiple email accounts to the same Dropbox account?

Tags: dropbox

I have both a school email and a Gmail account, and I'd like to be able to associate both to the same Dropbox account (so that people who know my school email can add me to shared folders etc. without confusion). Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. Dropbox has no such feature.

Comment: This is a fairly big limitation for professional use. I have many email accounts for various businesses, and 1 paid dropbox account that I tie to my personal gmail account. When various clients/partners want to share something, they use my relevant business emails. I find it quite unprofessional asking them to instead share the documents to my personal email address.

Answer (score 1):

From [Dropbox help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/61/en):

- Current option:

> ..option is to use a different Dropbox account for each user login on your computer. While this technically means you can have several Dropbox folders on the same computer, you will have to switch between each user account to take advantage of Dropbox's syncing features. This method is best for groups or families that have individual Dropbox accounts and use unique user logins on the same computer.

- Future option:

> Coming soon: Two Dropboxes, available everywhere
>
> Dropbox for Business users will be able to have both a personal Dropbox and a work Dropbox on any device. See our announcement.

Comment: This answers the question "can I have two accounts on the same device?", but the OP asked "can I have one account with two email addresses?".

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2018, you can now add a secondary email address to a Dropbox account.  But **you need a Professional, Plus, or Business account**.

If you have a Basic (free) account, the setting described below will simply be unavailable.

From the [help page](https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/secondary-email):

> Your email is the username for your Dropbox account. You can add a
>   secondary email to your Dropbox account.  By adding a secondary email,
>   you can route content shared with your primary or secondary email into
>   a single Dropbox account. Secondary emails are available to Dropbox
>   Professional, Plus, and Business customers.
>
> **Note:** Currently, Dropbox Professional and Plus members who are on a
>   free team are unable to add aliases. To use aliases, you’ll need to
>   leave your free team.

From the [help page](https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/secondary-email) explaining how to add a second email address:

> To add a secondary to your Dropbox account:
>
> 1. Sign in to dropbox.com
> 2. Click your avatar.
> 3. Click **Settings**.
> 4. Under the General section, scroll down to **Secondary email**.
> 5. Click **Edit**.
> 6. Click **Add a secondary email**.
> 7. Type the secondary email you’d like to add.
> 8. Click **Next**.
> 9. Click **Close**.
> 10. Open the email account you used for your secondary email. You should see a verification email.
> 11. Click **Verify your email** in the verification email.
> 12. You’ll be redirected to your Dropbox account, where you’ll see a confirmation message.
> 13. Click **Done**.
>
> You’ll have both a primary and secondary email(s) on your account.
>   Your primary email is the main email connected with your account.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - If people send shared file, folder, and Paper doc invites to your secondary email, you will receive the request and can accept them with
>     your primary email.
> - You can add multiple secondary emails.

See also: the [blog post](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Product-Updates/You-can-now-add-a-second-email-to-my-Dropbox-account/m-p/289760#M776) announcing the feature.